# Некорректная работа приложения

Tags: android

Начал писать игру на андроид, уже есть кое-что. Но это кое-что нормально работает только на моём собственном телефоне и на эмуляторе на компе, а на остальных устройствах то одно не работает, то другое. Хотя ничего сложного в игре не используется, и тестил на норм. андроид-телефонах. Подскажите, что делать или как искать в Интернете эту проблему? В Интернете не могу найти почему-то.

**UPD: РЕБЯТ!!!** Я умею искать ошибки и исправлять их, просто я думал, что можно соблюдать какие-то советы, рекомендации и так далее, чтобы приложение **работало без багов на 97% телефонов**, а не тестировать (или сделать автоматизацию тестирования) на огромном количестве телефонов, учитывая, что при количестве кода, например, в десятки тысяч строк, этих багов может оказаться крайне много на различных телефонах, которых тоже крайне много!!!

Comment: Ванговать не умеем, обозначь ошибку/глюк.

Comment: Разные: 
1) На двух самсунгах игра зависает после нажатия "Начать игру"
2) На одном HTC работает всё, кроме кнопки паузы

А я думал, что есть какие-то общие советы, рекомендации, темы по этому вопросу? Не на каждом же телефоне приложение проверять на отсутствие ошибок, коих может быть огромнейшее количество?

Comment: Искать любую проблему по стактрейсу( если он есть).    
Как именно не работает? Не запускается? не устанавливается? Крашится? Телефон уходит в ребут? В нарнию? В магазин за хлебом? Улетает в космос, исследовать далекие планеты?

Comment: Выкладывайте вашу игру в закрытое бета тестирование в гугл плей. Вы получите возможность собирать ошибки со всех устройств, где они происходят, исправлять их и автоматизированы обновлять своё приложение на всех устройствах

Comment: Я не занимаюсь дляандроидостроением, но там есть трассировки, логи, эмуляторы, корректоры ошибок, хаки для универсальности, etc.  
Ах да, есть ещё мозг, который должен обработать все эти сигналы :)  
Проблемный код в студию!

Comment: @TheDoctor, ну человек и выложит проект целиком )Человек правильно интересуется способами дебага, а не непосредственно решением на один конкретный момент.

Comment: @Etki Он создал игру и не может локализовать проблему. Это же бред какойто!

Comment: @Etki, зачем целиком?  
Достаточно проблемных участков, как это делают с JS или PHP.  
Хотя может в java чуть сложнее...

@argamidon, человек учится =)  
Я тоже когда-то не был образцом правильных вопросов (не то, чтобы сейчас профи :)), но опыт приходит со временем.

Comment: Народ, я знаю, как дебажить!!! Я просто думал, что можно как-то по-нормальному писать приложения, чтобы работало на 99% телефонов, а не так, чтобы работало на нескольких телефонах, а чтобы работало на всех остальных, надо тестить! Ибо тестить приложение в десятки тысяч строк на хотя бы 10 телефонах так, чтобы найти ВСЕ баги, и потом уже выкладывать приложение в маркет - это просто жесть, а ведь это только 10 телефонов, и выложив в маркет всё равно приложение получит плохой рейтинг из-за забагованности!!!

Повторяюсь: я знаю, как исправлять ошибки, вопрос не в этом!!!

Comment: @Aftorik, так задай вопрос нормально, а не "у меня есть программа, там ошиба, как ее исправить?"

Comment: @TheDoctor, потому что у него нет проблемных участков, он их не видит, он бы уже выложил их.

Comment: Java - write once, debug everywhere!

Comment: @argamidon слишком толсто. Тут беда не в Java, а в вендорах телефонов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*чтобы приложение работало без багов на 97% телефонов, а не тестировать*

Бог с Вами, сударь!
Без тестирования нельзя, основные ошибки выловишь сам, а тестировать *на огромном количестве телефонов* будешь по баг-репортам, так все живут.

Есть правила, которые лишь помогают избежать критичных ошибок, но не более.
Это что-то типа "Комментируй правильно код, т.е. юзай JavaDoc или аналоги" и "Избегай конструкции %something%, ибо опасна она и непредсказуема!".

Comment: @TheDoctor, Уууу.... :С Очень, очень-приочень жаль... И неужели нет никаких нигде тем хотя бы с какими-то советами по поводу ошибок, которые возникают на одних телефонах и не возникают на других? Ну или что-то такое, что может помочь таким, как я (да и вообще всем)?

Но, в любом случае, я не сдамся!

Comment: @Aftorik, никогда не сдаваться!  
Знаешь правду жизни: "Программист непосредственно пишет код только 20-30% времени, остальное на отладку" (точно не помню, но не важно)?

Comment: @TheDoctor, да, знаю не по наслышке, но всё же думал, что хотя бы в программировании под android будет так, как в UPD. Ведь, например, в приложениях на С++, Delphi под Windows это имеет место быть не просто в 97% устройств, а в 99.99% случаев!

А можешь тогда подсказать: в этом плане IDEA лучше, чем Eclipse?

Comment: Кстати, на основных моделях можно самому проверить через AVD (хотя вряд ли ТС об этом не знал, но всё может быть).

Comment: Вот изза этого я и слез с андроида. Полнейшая бредятина с совместимостью и переносимостью.

Answer (score 6):

1. Для начала прочтите [Android Device Compatibility Guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/compatibility.html) - там даны общие рекомендации, как писать совместимое приложение.
2. Создайте несколько разных эмуляторов с прицелом под разные версии Android'а и протестируйте под ними. У меня обычно их 3: GingerBread (API=10), ICS (API=14) и KitKat (API=19).
3. Обратите внимание, под каким API вы собираете приложение. Бывает, что люди собирают под LolliPop и пытаются запускать под GingerBread - запуститься, конечно, запустится, но если вы использовали фичи LolliPop или ICS, отсутствующие под GingerBread, - то результат понятен (скорее всего, это у вас и происходит). Запустите под Android Studio визард (по моему, называется code analysis), который ищет обращения к методам API, не совпадающим с объявленным в манифесте `minSdk`.
4. Если есть таковые классы и методы не поддерживаемые вашим `minSdk` - тогда придется погружаться в глубины [Android Support Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/index.html) - занятие не самое приятное, но необходимое.
5. Ну и, само собой, LogCat + отладчик + ACRA наше все.

Да и еще: пытаться поддерживать API Level < 10 (ниже GingerBread) - бессмысленно. Не стоит оно того.

Answer (score 2):

[[@Aftorik](/users/31756/aftorik)](/users/31756/aftorik) если ты не хочешь выкладывать код сюда, или не можешь локализовать проблему сам, то я тебе предложу прикрутить библиотеку ACRA к своей андроид игре. Даже если программа падает, ACRA всё равно создаст стактрейс и запишет это в файл или отправит на email (если, конечно, настроить).

Comment: @Aftorik, рекомендую Crashlytics. С ACRA нужно ещё хостинг для неё настраивать.

Comment: @argamidon, @Lucky_spirit - спасибо за советы, но прочтите UPD, пожалуйста. Вопрос не в этом

Answer (score 0):

Нашёл одну IDE, которая позволяет делать то, о чём я написал - Delphi от Embracadero (XE5, XE7 итд). Вот видео по правильной установке (смотреть обязательно): [Видео по правильной установке Delphi XE5](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NG4vL2kwf0U). На нём приложения пишутся так же, как оконные приложения для Windows на Delphi, но запускается на андроиде и работает везде всё идентично (по крайней мере, по моим скромным тестам на 5 телефонах). Правда, за широкие возможности не ручаюсь, но для простых приложений годится.

Из минусов ещё - большой вес apk-файла (>8 мб для простейшего приложения).

Из плюсов ещё - отсутствие всяких неведомых ошибок во время разработки. Вообще, разработка проходила как по маслу и совершенно без проблем.